# Generic constrained Map using higher-kinded-types?

Tags: scala, generics, constraints, higher-kinded-types

I am trying to implement a result cache (`Loader` class) that maps hashable instances of class `Resolver[T]` to `Result` instances, where `T` is has type of `Result`. Of course a user is given the possibility to specialize the the `Result` class providing extra methods that are application specific. The point is that using the `Loader.get` method the user has also to specify the resulting type:

```
    val s = Loader.get(new SpecializedResolver()).asInstanceOf[SpecializedResult]
```

What I want is to avoid the cast and make it implicit so the code should be something like:

```
    val implicitS = Loader.get(new SpecializedResolver())
```

The code I have at the moment is the following:

```
import scala.language.existentials

abstract class Result {
  def computed: Boolean
}

abstract class Resolver[T <: Result] {
    def result(): T forSome {type T <: Result}
}

class SpecializedResult extends Result {
  def computed = true
  def special() = 42
}

class SpecializedResolver extends Resolver[SpecializedResult] {
  def result = new SpecializedResult
}

object Loader {
  val cache = collection.mutable.Map[K forSome {type K <: Resolver[_]}, V forSome {type V <: Result}]()

  def get[K <: Resolver[_]](k: K): V forSome {type V <: Result} = {
    cache.getOrElseUpdate(k, { k.result } )
  }
}

object Runner {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val s = Loader.get(new SpecializedResolver()).asInstanceOf[SpecializedResult]
    println("Value is: %d".format(s.special))

    val implicitS = Loader.get(new SpecializedResolver())
    // test.scala:34: error: value special is not a member of Result
    println("Value is: %d".format(implicitS.special))
  }
}
```

Since I am relatevely new to the scala language my question is: is it even possible to achieve this implicit cast by using higher-kinded-types feature that scala provides? I took a look at the talk ['High Wizardry in the Land of Scala'](http://vimeo.com/28793245) where the speaker Daniel Spiewak introduces a higher-order `HOMap` that does something similar but I still don't well understand how to adapt his solution to my case.

Comment: I think what you want is encoded in Shapeless https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you don't need all the existentials here. In some cases they're just overly verbose—`K forSome { type K <: Resolver[_] }`, for example, is exactly the same as `K <: Resolver[_]`. In other cases they introduce behavior that seems to be unintended. For example:

```
class FooResult extends Result { def computed = true }
class BarResult extends Result { def computed = true }

object Foo extends Resolver[FooResult] { def result() = new BarResult }
```

This compiles just fine, because the `T` in the return type of `result` shadows the class's type parameter `T`.

Next, have you considered lazy values here? They'd take care of this kind of caching for you—you just define `result` as `lazy val result = ...` in your `Resolver` implementations and the result will be computed exactly once (when it's first needed).

If you decide you need to handle this caching manually, this is a situation where you may be able to justify bullying the compiler with a cast. For example, given the following setup:

```
trait Result { def computed: Boolean }
trait Resolver[T <: Result] { def result(): T }
```

We can write:

```
object Loader {
  private[this] val cache = collection.mutable.Map.empty[Resolver[_], Result]

  def get[V <: Result](k: Resolver[V]): V =
    cache.getOrElseUpdate(k, k.result()).asInstanceOf[V]

}
```

We know that the types will work out, since there's only one way for pairs to get into the map.

Update: My `Loader` solution here is essentially the same as Sergey's (note though that it's a good idea to lock down the map, and that you don't need brackets around the call to `result`, since the second parameter of `getOrElseUpdate` is by-name). I'm leaving my answer anyway because the first half is the important part.

Comment: This is exactly the same answer that I want to post, if I have more time and better English :) Don't remove it!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Regarding the point of using lazy variables I was aware of this feature, but the point is that Result instances are shared by different classes in different contexts that's why I need a specific caching solution. Regarding the existential you are right I was abusing them for no specific reason. So thanks for the explanation in the first half of your post. Really appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

In your case you can use simple solution (only changed code):

```
abstract class Resolver[T <: Result] {
    def result(): T
}
object Loader {
  val cache = collection.mutable.Map[Resolver[_], Any] ()

  def get[K <: Result](k: Resolver[K]): K = {
    cache.getOrElseUpdate(k, { k.result } ).asInstanceOf[K]
  }
}
```